# integration over area

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $D=\{(x,y)|0<x<y<9x, 1<xy<4\}$. Integrate $$I=\int_D \sqrt{\frac{y}{x}}+\sqrt{xy}dxdy$$

I've got $6+7\log(3)$ as answer by using $xy=u$ and $y/x=v$ then $2I=\int_1^9\int_1^4\frac{1}{\sqrt v}+\frac{\sqrt u}{v}dudv$. But the answer sheet says it is $6+\frac{14}{3}\log(3)$. Which one is correct?

Comment: Why $1\le u\le4$ ?

Comment: I had a mistake, I corrected it! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$2I=\int_1^9\int_1^4\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt v}+\frac{\sqrt u}{v}\right)dudv=\int_1^9\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt v}+\frac{2 u\sqrt{u}}{3v}\right)\Big{|}_{1}^{4}\,\,dv$$
$$2I=\int_1^9\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt v}+\frac{14}{3v}\right)\,\,dv$$
$$2I=\left(6{\sqrt v}+\frac{14}{3}\ln(v)\right)\Big{|}_{1}^{9}$$
$$2I=12+\frac{14}{3}\ln(9)$$
$$I=6+\frac{7}{3}\ln(9)=6+\frac{14}{3}\ln(3)$$

Comment: Aha, I made a very silly mistake! Thank you very much!